Line:column display for commit message in IntelliJ
For previous versions of IntelliJ IDEA I was able to see the line:column display for my cursor when I was writing a commit message. For new versions I'm seeing this feature not available anymore and I'm just seeing the line:column for the editor tab. Do you know if there is any hidden configuration or something to re-enable this feature?

Thanks in advance for your comments/answers
Best regards.

Please see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-74306/LineColumn-indicator-no-longer-corresponds-to-caret-in-the-Commit-tool-window
Feel free to drop a comment and vote up.
